# How can I check how many hours of YouTube I watch daily?

Tags: youtube

Is there an easy way to visualize my viewing data without manually crawling my YouTube history daily? Further, can these be categorized by uploader, length, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I have actually seen about 20 different versions of this question - all slightly different. So, when I saw how many there were, I decided I was going to find a solution...

Unfortunately, after about 9 hours of non-stop reading, writing, inspecting, adding and deleting - I am still unable to find a viable way of bypassing Google (YouTube)'s code implementation.

For all intents and purposes, and for the specific METHOD by which you (and quite a few others) would like to be able to obtain the information, this is not possible.

By saying that, I mean that it will not be practical for someone to do, because of some crazy things that YouTube does to protect the use of this information in such a way (although I have **absolutely** no idea why they go to such great lengths.

**BUT I was able to locate a few things that might be of interest.**

If you access the page on the actual YOUTUBE site - under HISTORY - you will be able to see all the videos. You may also change a few things to limit the results to a certain time frame. BUT - the only two ways by which you will be able to ascertain the time (in xx\yy - [xx]=finished portion of the video \ [yy]total run-time of video) is by inspecting the elements of the page (Usually F12).

Now, it's a pretty technical process and if you're trying to use it for that reason, you probably would already be better just going without the information because quite honestly it is not worth it...otherwise for anyone who knows what their doing, and is interested, there actually IS a place in the CSS that you can find the code that is being executed (rather, blocked from being executed) and it is as follows:

< div class="fp-display-item-yt-duration"

Now, when pressing CTRL+F and typing in (some OR all) of that line - you will be able to find the watched\run-time of each video **currently** on the page.

By **absolutely NO means** is this convenient. Furthermore, there are a LOT of blocked scripts being denied in the CSS as soon as it is opened...

Again, I have no clue why - but they dont want it being used anymore for some reason...but initially before I discovered this, I thought it might be feasible to implement a bare-bones program to run some real quick HTML [Find] commands  and possibly interlace all the values - and then output them to a type of Excel algorithm which would then give a combined total of both fields...[xx/yy]

I don't think this is NOT possible, because I was able to copy all the CSS as HTML and paste into my own editor, from which I could then apply a variety of rules aside from that of the website CSS - which could come in handy if the right person could process and use the information - because its there and able to be seen, for sure.

If anyone wants to take on that task, Id be more than happy to do what I can - because I feel like its a ridiculous thing to not be able to access and it makes absolutely no sense to me....I dont even want the feature whatsoever, I just want to figure out a way around it! LOL

Hopefully someone gets some use out of this....I tried my best to figure at least SOMETHING out, guys!

Sorry I couldn't get any further tho =\